# Use HttpURLConnection in company's intranet

Tags: java, request

I'm writing a java program which is using HttpURLConnection to connect a url. But the problem is the url is a intra url of my company, so I have to connect my company's wifi to visit it. But there are some strategies in my company's network which doesn't allow me to use command like "ping" or "nslookup":
[image]

And same problem occurs when I was using HttpURLConnection:
[image]

I don't understand why I can visit www.google.com in my Browser but cannot connect it in java or command line. I think there's no problem with my laptop because I tried the same things in my home's wifi environment and everything works fine. But in my home's wifi I cannot visit the company's intra url. I know my description is confusing, so the situation is :

In company's wifi environment:

```
I can visit google in browser
I can visit the company's url which I want to connect in java
I cannot ping/nslookup google
I cannot connect google or company's url in java(UnknownHostException)
```

In home's wifi environment:

```
I can visit google in browser
I cannot visit the company's url which I want to connect in java
I can ping/nslookup google
I can connect google in java
I cannot connect company's url in java
```

So is it possible for me to connect my company's url in java in my company's wifi environment? Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `"http://www.google.com"` instead of `"www.google.com"`?

Comment: You need to set up your HTTP proxy via system properties. See [Java Networking and Proxies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html).

Comment: @JonnyHenly If he hadn't *already* used `http://www.google.com` in the first place he wouldn't be going through all that HTTP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the organizations use proxy servers for internet traffic.

Your browser must be using a proxy, which should be able to resolve the host names itself or by using another DNS server. You should check your browser settings and grab the proxy settings from there and use it in your code. One of the way to use proxy settings in code is by setting System properties like this:

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "host");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "port_number");
System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "user");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "password");
```

Comment: Not one of those methods exists.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, not sure from where i learnt those :-p Updated to use system property.

Comment: The user/password properties don't exist either, except in the Apache HTTP Client and other third-party stuff. See the Networking and Proxies document I cited in comment above.